# How can I write a stand alone recursive function to print the levels of all the non-leaf nodes of a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

So, the is the problem statement where I am stuck and trying to seek help for it is the following: As a part of my assignment, we have been asked to print the levels of the all the non-leaf nodes of a Binary Search Tree. We have been the function's template:

```
int Print_Non_leaf_Level(BST *Root)
```

And below is the memory of an object of the following class acts as the node of a linked list representing Binary Search Tree of integers.

```
   class BST{
    private: int info;
             BST *left;
             BST *right;
    public: BST () {} //NULL Constructor.
    };
```

Following is what I tried to do, but I am not sure if my logic is correct.

```
int Print_Non_leaf_Level(BST *Root){
    BST *temp;
    int level=-1;
    temp = Root;
    if(temp!=null){
       if(temp->left !=null || temp->right != null){
          ++level;
          cout<<level<<'\n';
       }
       Print_Non_leaf_Level(temp->left);
       Print_Non_leaf_Level(temp->right);
       return level;
    }
}
```

Comment: To begin with your function is not recursive, it doesn't even have a loop. And are you allowed to write helper functions?

Comment: I believe you will want your constructor to assign 'left' and 'right' to the value nullptr;

Comment: There are a few gaps in the information. For example, the declaration of the recursive function includes the keyword `friend` which implies that it should be inside the definition of the  node class, `BST`. Is there anything else missing? If you could provide a [mcve] that would help.

Comment: no helper functions and I have edited my code.

Comment: `int info; BST *left; BST *right;` all 3 need default values where pointers are nullptr.

Comment: You’re not sure if it’s correct? Haven’t you noticed that it prints zero on all levels?

Comment: I am not sure if that's why I put it up here. If you can suggest me a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you want a *free standing* function to *iterate* through your tree, you should provide *iterator* support.  An iterator object.  A way to increment the iterator and dereference it.  Maybe also a function that indicates if the node is leaf or not.

Comment: Consider the implications of `Print_Non_leaf_Level(temp->left, level+1);`